# Can I use NextUI and Tailwinds in the same project?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

I have a preexisting project with Tailwinds, and I would like to add Next UI to it to be able to hook into their components, but also maintain my old themes for Tailwinds without having to redo everything I've done so far with Next UI styling. Is this possible?

edit:
For context, I've followed the installation guide and am running into some errors where applying styles to a Next UI component does not work.

ex:  `<Button color="primary">Button Text</Button>` will not display any color and instead shows a transparent button.

Trying to deduce if this is an issue with my configuration, or what. I'm inclined to believe that these can coexist due to lines in the documentation such as "common colors is disabled by default to avoid collisions with Tailwind" but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does your tailwind.config.js look like? Looks like the most common way to change NextUI components style is with the color prop, which can be customized via the tailwind.config.js

Comment: @Rico So i have all of the stuff listed in the [setup guide](https://nextui.org/docs/guide/installation) step 2, along with a pre-existing `theme: {extend: { colors: {...}, font-family: {...}, etc...}}`. I also added within the plugin: `nextui({defaultTheme: 'dark', defaultExtendTheme: 'dark', themes: {dark: {colors: {...}}, light : {colors: {...}}}})`

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @SerhiyMamedov No error, rather the props that I pass do not reflect in the the component (i.e. `<Button radius="md" />` will still be a button with square corners)

Comment: @reeslabree have you tried to use `className` instead?

Comment: @SerhiyMamedov what would the usage be? `<Button className={?} />`

Comment: @reeslabree check this docs: https://nextui.org/docs/customization/override-styles#overriding-a-component